# How can I register multiple global shortcuts in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm building a prototype on top of https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start

I have the following code in **main.js** and nothing else in other files:

```
const electron = require('electron')
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')
const globalShortcut = electron.globalShortcut
const {clipboard} = require('electron')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
    globalShortcut.unregisterAll();
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', function() {
  createWindow();
  globalShortcut.register('Alt+h', () => {
    let date = new Date();
    clipboard.writeText(date.toLocaleString());
  });

  globalShortcut.register('Alt+c', function() {
    clipboard.writeText('Multitabler spin 2 tables');
  });
})

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

On the 'ready' event, I register two shortcuts: Alt+h and Alt+c. Alt+h works in the sense that the date is copied to my clipboard but the other shortcut doesn't produce any output to the clipboard.

**What have I tried**:
I tried to replace the clipboard write event in the second shortcut with a console.log statement. I got no output when I pressed that key combination.

How can I register multiple global short-codes that activate regardless if the app is focused or minimized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code actually works. I tested on my windows and mac. Maybe it's shortcut key conflict, Alt+c may have been taken by some other software.

Moreover I recommend you to register shortcut on windows focus instead of app ready, cause Electron will block other softwares, which using the same shortcut key to function.

```
const refreshCommand = process.platform === 'darwin' ? 'Cmd+R' : 'F5'

app.on('browser-window-focus', () => {
globalShortcut.register(refreshCommand, () => {
    // do something
})
})

app.on('browser-window-blur', () => {
globalShortcut.unregisterAll()
})
```